# Execute a dbt model only when if condition is true

Tags: model, macros, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jinja2, dbt

I am pretty new to dbt and any help will be appreciated.
I have a model which inserts data into target table a.
Now if the target table (in snowflake) has data existing for passed input date the insertion model should not run.
So how to call a model from if else block of jinja/macro
Ref () is not working as the query is insert command

Ref calling from model

Comment: can you try adding a filter like `where source_date > (select max(target_date) from {{this}} ) ` to the model. This will check if data is new in source or not, if yes then only produce rows

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This sounds like an `incremental` strategy to me. Have you checked this docs here? https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/incremental-models

Comment: Where does the date come from, a source model? an env var?

Comment: Thanks for the help yes we have incremental solution but again I don't want to invoke the model itself. As incremental we have to execute a query on top of target table and current query for that date . In dbt the model will get invoked unnecessarily during run and consume sometime there